# I can't run Eclipse on Macbook on Yosemite: "Version 1.6.0_65 of the JVM is not suitable for this product." and I have Java 1.8 (shows in settings)

Tags: macos, java, eclipse

I can't run Eclipse on Macbook on Yosemite: "Version 1.6.0_65 of the JVM is not suitable for this product." and I have Java 1.8. When I open settings I can see that version of Java is 1.8

Comment: Please include the version of your Eclipse, as well as the output of running `java -version` on Terminal.

Comment: Currently? Now I have this:    

  -bash: java: command not found  

Eclipse PDT is:  

    eclipse-php-mars-2-macosx-cocoa-x86_64(1).tar.gz

Comment: Did you install JDK 8 from [Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html)?

Comment: Yes. I did. Yes.

Comment: When I run java -version I get the proper java version too (1.83):  

    `java -version`  
    `java version "1.8.0_73"`
`Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_73-b02)`
`Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.73-b02, mixed mode)`

(I edited .bashrc for PATH to point to proper java version)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally this worked for me. Add this line to the .plist inside Eclipse application Contents subfolder with version of jdk you want to use:
-vm/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_73.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java

Comment: I was just trying that and that actually solved the problem! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It has worked for me to change inside `info.plist`

```
<key>JVMVersion</key>
```

from
`<string>1.6*,1.7+</string>` to `<string>1.8*,1.6*,1.7+</string>`

and inside `./bin/idea.properties`
change `JVMVersion=1.6*` to `JVMVersion=1.8*`